# Estimation of carbon stock value

Tags: ecology, database, data, conservation-biology, vegetation

[image: this is the formula I found, same type but different formula][image: this is too]I would like to ask, to calculate the carbon value estimation, the Allometric formula is of course used, but in some of the literature I searched, I found different allometric formulas but the same type of plant species. So I have a little confusion about which formula to use as the basis of my research. Could you please explain/help me on what I should do to solve my problem? Thank you everyone